# Wordpress - The Templates drop-down menu lists up to 9 items?

Tags: php, wordpress

The Templates drop-down menu does not display all my templates. Is there a maximum number that can be displayed? I have 10 templates but I exempt a maximum of 9 templates. How do I list all? I am using Using WP 4.9.

[image: WP template List]

And

[image: My Template List]

Comment: I imagine it's related to this ballsup - https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42573 . There are workarounds in the thread, bumping version numbers etc.

Comment: Thanks McNab, that was exactly it. The problem was in vs 4.9 which caches the list of files obtained from themes, and can take 1 hour to update.

Comment: Hi Andre, great glad you got it sorted.  You could add that as an answer and mark your own answer as correct if you want.  Welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks McNab, that was exactly it. The problem was in vs 4.9 which caches the list of files obtained from themes, and can take 1 hour to update.