# Custom page template for global use , don't showing up in wordpress template dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I searched everywhere and could not find.
Now you are my only hope, please help.

Custom page template for global use , don't showing up in wordpress template dropdown when i create custom floder for the template parts.

My-theme/global_template.php WORK 
My-theme/template-parts/global_template.php WORK 
**My-theme/template-parts/archive/global_template.php DON'T WORK**

**How can I make folders that inside template-parts that contain templates to appear in page attributes->template?**

[image: Custom page template loaction]

Here the code inside global_template.php

[image: Custom page template code]

As you see there is no test template..
[image: page attributes]

Comment: Blame Caching. This is a new 'feature' introduced into 4.9 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47558838/wordpress-the-templates-drop-down-menu-lists-up-to-9-items?noredirect=1#comment82141479_47558838

Comment: Hello, i know about caching problem with wordpress 4.9. But it's not it... the templates work... But only in some folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the depth the function thats get the templates have 1 depth. so you must put the files in the theme root or first sub-folder

The core functions `get_post_templates()` call `get_files()` with depth 1 and it pass it on to the function `scandir()` that scan the directories.

You can add more templates manually like this replace the `{$post_type}` in the `add_filter` with the post type that you want to add the templates to. for example `page`.

```
/**
* @param array $post_templates Array of page templates.
* Keys are filenames, values are translated names.
*/
function extend_post_type_templates($post_templates, $this, $post, $post_type) {
    $post_templates['template-parts/archive/global_template.php'] = 'Name for this';
    return $post_templates;
}
add_filter( 'theme_{$post_type}_templates', 'extend_post_type_templates', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: So it's WordPress limitation? 
Can I change the depth, without hardcode it?

Comment: Yes see the answer now.